# MYSQL query with multiple reference tables

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

users

```
id | fname | lname 
1  | Ron   | Jones
2  | Jon   | Don
3  | Sam   | Bolt
```

niche

```
id | name
1  | Arts
2  | Sports
3  | Fashion
```

compensation

```
id | type
1  | Monetary Payments
2  | Free Products
3  | Experiences
```

Then I have two reference tables:

user_niche

```
id | userid | nicheid
1  |   1    |   2
2  |   1    |   3
3  |   2    |   1
4  |   2    |   3
5  |   3    |   1
6  |   3    |   2
```

And finally user_comp

```
id | userid | compid
1  |   1    |   1
2  |   1    |   2
3  |   2    |   3
4  |   3    |   1
5  |   3    |   2
6  |   3    |   3
```

What I want to achieve through query is as follows:

```
users.id |  users.fname | users.lname |      niches      |          compensations
   1     |    Ron       |    Jones    |  Sports, Fashion | Monetary Payments, Free Products 
   2     |    Jon       |    Don      |  Arts, Fashion   | Experiences  
   3     |    Sam       |    Bolt     |  Arts, Sports    | Monetary Payments, Free Products, Experiences
```

But my query (as follows) keeps repeating the niches and compensations in a way I cannot understand. Can someone please help me accomplish the required result?

```
SELECT users.id, users.fname, users.lname, GROUP_CONCAT(niche.name) AS niches, GROUP_CONCAT(compensation.type) AS compensations
    FROM users 
    JOIN user_niche ON users.id = user_niche.userid
    JOIN user_comp ON users.id = user_comp.userid
    JOIN niche ON user_niche.nicheid = niche.id
    JOIN compensation ON user_comp.compid = compensation.id
    GROUP BY users.id
```

Help and suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT table.column)`

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Thanks @Akina. That solves the issue!